# $X$ compact metric implies $X$ separable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, separable-spaces

I want to show that a compact metric space is a separable space.

Attempt:
Suppose $X$ is compact. Then it is complete and totally bounded. Taking $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ in the definition of total boundedness gives me $\exists x_1,x_2,\ldots,$ such that $X\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^nB_{\frac{1}{n}}(x_i)$..

how to continue?

Comment: Let $A_n:= \{x_1,...x_n\}$, the centers of the finite subcovers for balls with radius $1/n$. Then take $\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$, this set is countable and dense.

Comment: I understand why it is countable since the union of countable many points is once again countable. How do we know that set is dense though?

Comment: Try to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ and $x\in X$, there exists $x_\epsilon \in X$ such that $d(x, x_\epsilon) < \epsilon$. Hint: there is a cover of $X$ with balls of radius $1/n < \epsilon$, also that the center of these balls are in $A = \cup_n A_n$.

Comment: @Xiao Actually $A_n=\left\{x_1,\ldots,x_{N_n}\right\}$, to avoid confusions.

Comment: Compact does not imply separable, you may consider inserting the word metric in the title of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is compact, there are points $\{x_i^{(n)}\}_{i=1}^{k_n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and finite $k_n$, such that 
$$
 X \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{k_n} B(x_i,1/n) \qquad (n \in \mathbb N)
$$
Now take the union of all the $x_i^{(n)}$ to get a countable  dense subset of $X$.